# DTCoreText with Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is it possible to use DTCoreText in MonoTouch or is there a native library that does what DTCoreText does?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText (but I haven't used it myself).

Then you just have to [create a MonoTouch binding](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries) to be able to use it from MonoTouch.

Comment: Thanks Rolf.  That looks pretty intense. I found that there is an AttributedText property on UILabel.  However it does not appear that NSAttributedString.initWithHTML is available.   Is there a way to call that from MT?

Comment: Never mind, foudn that that is not available.  Hopefully someone has already created the bindings.

Comment: @user1982219 Did you find the bindings for this? Since the bindings have been asked for multiple times and nobody have done it then maybe binding this library is not that trivial?